# Image ROI from depth information

Tags: c++, opencv, ros

I am using a SICK TIM laser scanner to get a 2D scan of flat rectangular object. I know the dimensions of the object, the transformation between the laser scanner and the camera and the camera's calibration matrix. Based the laser scan data, I know the exact position and orientation of the object in the real world.

[image]

This image shows the base of the object with respect to the laser scanner.

Based on this information, how can I determine the ROI of the object in the image? I can't do any kind of edge detection or feature detection before the ROI is found out. I am using OpenCV for this purpose.

The problem seems to be reverse of stereo vision where I have to get the depth information from a camera image.

Comment: what are you talking about? What do you mean by Region of Interest? Surely that data subsample depends on what you are studying? And Stereo vision is where you estimate depth from a camera image not the reverse

Comment: By Region of Interest I mean to find the projection of the object in the image.